# Jordan content $0 \implies \text{volume} \ 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove that Jordan content $0 \implies \text{volume} \ 0$. The definition of Jordan content 0 I was given is: "Set $A$ is said to have Jordan content $0$, if for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a finite collection of open rectangles that covers $A$, whose total volume is less than $\epsilon$."

My attempt:
Since $A$ has Jordan content 0, there exists a finite collection of rectangles $R_i, i = 1,...,n$ such that $A \subset \cup_{i=1}^n R_i$ and $vol(\sum_{i=1}^n R_i) < \epsilon $ for all $\epsilon > 0$. Hence $vol(A) < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$, therefore $vol(A) = 0.$ Is my proof valid?

EDIT: $vol(D) = \int_D 1_D = \int_I \hat{1}_I,$ where $\hat{1}_I$ is the zero-extension of 1 from a set $D$ to the generalized rectangle $I.$ And volume of a generalized rectangle to be the product of the lengths
of its edges.

Comment: What is the definition of "volume" here? Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @DavidLui, I've edited my question

Comment: That proof is correct, just note that $vol(\sum_{i=1}^n R_i)$ for different choices of $R_i$  is cofinal subset of the set of Riemann sums, so if the integral exists then it must converge to what $vol(\sum_{i=1}^n R_i)$ converges to, which is 0.